# Hybrid Bayesian Network with Continuous Parents and Ordinal Child Node (Softmax Function)

Tags: generalized-linear-model, bayesian-network, ordered-logit, softmax

Upon reading about hybrid BNs with discrete child nodes and multiple continuous parents, I came across the possibility of using the softmax (multinomial logit) function (below) in order to query conditional probabilities.

$$\Pr(R=i \mid X=x) = \frac{\exp(w^\prime_i x + b_i)}{\sum_j \exp(w^\prime_j x + b_j)}$$

My question is whether such a function can be extended to cover multinomial ordinal child variables (First, Second, Third, etc) and if so, how is order enforced?